# newcounter, crefname, crefformat: Multiple cross-references in cref not showing name, ?? instead

Tags: counters, cleveref

After defining a `newcounter` (I named it "cases"), `crefname`, `crefformat`, and `crefrangeformat`, I incremented the counter with `refstepcounter` and labeled it with `label`.  I can reference single cases with `cref` and multiple cases with `labelcref` and `crefrange`; however, when referencing multiple cases with `cref`, the type is not displayed like it is with the other methods.  What am I missing?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{My New Section}
\newcounter{cases}
\crefname{cases}{Case Study}{Case Studies}
\crefformat{cases}{Case Study~#2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{cases}{Case Studies~#3#1#4 through~#5#2#6}

\Cref{case:a} comes first.
Next is \cref{case:b}.
Altogether, we have \cref{case:b,case:a}.  %This shows ?? instead of "Case Studies" and "and".  How do I fix this?
Trying again, we have Case Studies \labelcref{case:b,case:a}.
With a range, we have \crefrange{case:a}{case:b}.

\refstepcounter{cases} \label{case:a}
\textbf{Case Study \thecases:}
Blah.

\refstepcounter{cases} \label{case:b}
\textbf{Case Study \thecases:}
Blah.

\end{document}
```

[image: Output Generated by the MWE.]

An additional note:  I am using a counter for these Case Studies instead of the theorem environment because the cases are relatively lengthy compared to a typical theorem and I do not want the special formatting that comes with the theorem environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\crefname` and similar instructions should go *before* `\begin{document}` as should `\newcounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\newcounter{cases}
\crefname{cases}{Case Study}{Case Studies}
\crefformat{cases}{Case Study~#2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{cases}{Case Studies~#3#1#4 through~#5#2#6}

\begin{document}

\section{My New Section}

\Cref{case:a} comes first.
Next is \cref{case:b}.
Altogether, we have \cref{case:b,case:a}.
Trying again, we have Case Studies \labelcref{case:b,case:a}.
With a range, we have \crefrange{case:a}{case:b}.

\refstepcounter{cases} \label{case:a}
\textbf{Case Study \thecases:}
Blah.

\refstepcounter{cases} \label{case:b}
\textbf{Case Study \thecases:}
Blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution!  I see this now in the `cleveref` documentation but wish it were more forceful in wording, like "should" instead of "can" and "expects" instead of "allows".

From the Abstract (p. 1) (emphasis added):
"The formatting for each cross-reference type _can_ be fully customised in the preamble of your document."

From the Introduction (p. 3) (emphasis added):
"The `cleveref` package _allows_ you to define the format for the different types of cross-references once-and-for-all in the preamble of your document."